# MacOS IPv6 "happy eyeballs" diagnostic CLI performance tool

Tags: macos, command-line, ipv6

"Happy Eyeballs" is the IPv6 feature (RFC8305) where the OS tests response time on IPv4 and IPv6 per destination and tries to optimize performance by choosing the "fastest" protocol for hostnames which have both A-records and AAAA-records.  Some recent implementations also give a preference to IPv6 (I've heard of preferences from 25msec to 300msec).

I remember seeing a MacOS CLI which showed the recorded response times by destination.  I don't remember the name of the tool, and have not been able to find it in macOS Catalina (10.15).

Does anyone remember the name of the MacOS CLI which shows the response-time by network destination?

EDIT AFTER ANSWERED.  I just want to show how cool this command is using preformatted text.  Make sure to scroll to the right to see the bytes-in/bytes-out/round-trip-time by website/socket for the webkit process.

```
nettop -m tcp -J rtt_min,rtt_var,bytes_in,bytes_out -p 40893
                                                                                                  bytes_in       bytes_out   rtt_min   rtt_var
    com.apple.WebKi.40893                                                                           99 KiB         209 KiB
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49492<->lb-192-30-253-124-iad.github.com:443                             3628 B          1009 B    72.56 ms  16.12 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49479<->104.244.42.66:443                                                5091 B          1648 B    17.72 ms   7.69 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49467<->lb-140-82-114-25-iad.github.com:443                              3783 B          1184 B    81.22 ms   6.75 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49448<->stackoverflow.com:443                                            3951 B          1035 B    83.03 ms  22.56 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49441<->151.101.129.69:443                                                 64 KiB          50 KiB   9.94 ms   0.62 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49269<->ec2-34-192-92-205.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443                      13 KiB         151 KiB  77.75 ms   7.94 ms
       tcp4 192.168.0.10:49245<->lb-140-82-113-25-iad.github.com:443                              4651 B          2196 B    79.12 ms   0.62 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nettop -n -m route
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yes!  But it fooled me: you have to expand the terminal window to the right to see the rtt_avg figure.  This is a good option to make it more obvious: "nettop -n -m route -J rtt_var,rtt_min" or this "nettop -n -J rtt_var,rtt_min"

Answer (score 3):

Response times by destination are returned by the `ping` utility.

Comment: @zx485: Why not? Ping is the first tool any professional will use for network testing. It has parameters for every aspect of its operation, and can stay discreetly in the background while continuously testing connection and  response times.

Comment: @zx485: If no better tool turns up, ping/ping6 is excellent in what it does.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but "nettop -n -J rtt_var,rtt_min" was the command I vaguely remembered which shows response time by socket (which is really cool).  Ping shows response time by IP.  Upvoted.